# Find all points M such that area(MBC)=area(ABC)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, locus

Let ABC a triangle, find the set $\Gamma$ of points M so that $Area(\triangle MBC)=Area(\triangle ABC)$ without using dot product.

I treat $Area(\triangle ABC)$ as constant $ \delta$ and define $h$ as the altitude from the vertice A. If $M_0$ is point such that $d(M_0, (BC))=h$ then $\Gamma$ is the line passing through $M_0$ and parallel to $(BC)$.
Here  the problem is $h$ is still undefined.

Comment: Your analysis is fine: the locus of $M$ is the line through $A$ parallel to $BC$.

Comment: There is another line which fit. The symmetric of the line parallel to (BC) passing through A by the reflection of axis (BC)

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $l_1||BC$ and $A\in l_1$.

Also, le $l_2$ be the line symmetric to $l_1$ respect to line $BC$.

Now, easy to see that for all $M\in l_1\cup l_2$ we have $S_{\Delta ABC}=S_{\Delta MBC}.$

Let $M\notin l_1\cup l_2$.

We have two cases.

1. $M$ is placed between $l_1$ and $l_2$.

In this case $S_{\Delta MBC}<S_{\Delta ABC}.$

2. $M$ is not placed between $l_1$ and $l_2$.

In this case $S_{\Delta MBC}>S_{\Delta ABC}.$

We checked all points of the plane, which says that $l_1\cup l_2$ is a needed locus.